# Object of class could not be converted to string Symfony2 error

Tags: symfony, object

I get this error:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Mihail\SearchBundle\Entity\FileSearch could not be converted to string") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 13.

Using symfony 2.8LTS.
Here are the files I am using to basically create a search form in my own bundle, that searches in app directory, based on what search criteria is provided in the form. 
**Search Controller:**

```
<?php

 namespace Mihail\SearchBundle\Controller;

 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
 use Mihail\SearchBundle\Entity\FileSearch;
 use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
 use Mihail\SearchBundle\Form\Type\SearchType;

 class SearchController extends Controller
 {
     /**
      * @Route("/search")
      */
     public function searchAction(Request $request)
     {
         $search = new FileSearch();

        $dirsList = $this->generateDirsList();

         $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, $search, array('dirs_list' => $dirsList));

         $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $searchContent = $form->get('searchContent')->getData();
            $fileType = $form->get('fileType')->getData();
            $searchDir = $form->get('searchDir')->getData();

            $finder = new Finder();
            if(isset($fileType))
            {
                $finder->files()->name("*.$fileType");
            }

            if(isset($searchDir))
            {
                $finder->files()->in($searchDir);
            }else{
                $finder->files()->in(__DIR__);
            }

            if(isset($searchContent))
            {
                $finder->contains($searchContent);
            }

            if(isset($finder) && count($finder)>0)
            {
                echo "Found results in $searchDir: <br/>";
                foreach ($finder as $key => $value) {
                    echo "<h4> $value contains '$searchContent' </h4>";
                }
            }else{
                echo "No content '$searchContent' in '$searchDir'";
            }
        }

         return $this->render('MihailSearchBundle:randomsearch:search_form.html.twig', array(
             'form' => $form->createView(),
         ));
     }

     public function generateDirsList()
     {
        $path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir();
        $finder = new Finder();

        $iterator = $finder
            ->ignoreUnreadableDirs()
            ->directories()
            ->depth('< 2')
            ->in($path);

        $dirsList = array();
        foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
            $dirsList["$value"] = "$value";
        }

        return $dirsList;
     }
 }
```

**File Search Fields get and set**

```
<?php

 namespace Mihail\SearchBundle\Entity;

 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

 class FileSearch
 {

    protected $searchContent;

    protected $fileType;

    protected $searchDir;

    public function getSearchContent()
     {
         return $this->searchContent;
     }

     public function setSearchContent($searchContent)
     {
         $this->searchContent = $searchContent;
     }

     public function getFileType()
     {
        return $this->fileType;
     }

     public function setFileType($fileType)
     {
        $this->fileType = $fileType;
     }

     public function getSearchDir()
     {
        return $this->searchDir;
     }

     public function setSearchDir($searchDir)
     {
        $this->searchDir = $searchDir;
     }
 }
```

**Search type for creating the form**

```
<?php

 namespace Mihail\SearchBundle\Form\Type;

 use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
 use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

 class SearchType extends AbstractType
 {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
     {
         $builder
             ->add('searchContent', TextType::class, array('label'=> 'Search Content:* '))
             ->add('fileType', TextType::class , array('label'=> 'File Type:'))
             ->add('searchDir',  ChoiceType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Search Path:',
                'choices' => $options['dirs_list'],
                'choices_as_values' => true))
             ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Search for File'));
     }

     public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired(array(
            'dirs_list',
        ));

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Mihail\SearchBundle\Entity\FileSearch',
            'dirs_list' => null,
        ));
    }
 }
```

**A simple twig template to render the form fields**

```
{# Mihail/SearchBudnle/Resources/views/randomsearch/search_form.html.twig #}

    {{ form(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_row(form.fileType) }}
        {{ form_row(form.searchContent) }}
        {{ form_row(form.searchDir) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've had these errors before when using a choice field and not providing a _toString for the option entities. However it doesn't seem that your FileSearch is used in a choice field. Perhaps try adding _toString method to your FileSearch entity and see if it appears on the form anywhere. Might shed some light into what is going on.

Comment: I added __toString()
{ return $this->searchDir;} 
to the FileSearch, now I get this error
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Method Mihail\SearchBundle\Entity\FileSearch::__toString() must return a string value") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 13.

Comment: Can you show your form_div_layout.html.twig ?

Comment: I only use one twig template - form_search.html.twig, i don't have a form_div_layout.html.div file. I think it is some built in twig file.EDIT Found it in some symfony folder here is a link, cant post here, too long: http://paste2.org/ty8zstdx

Comment: Try returning any string in the _toString method. The line 13 from form_div_layout is: ...<input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>... so it looks like one of your input fields (searchContent or fileType) is having an instance of FileSearch passed to it as a value instead of a text value. Try commenting out each of those in turn to find which one it is.

Comment: OK, so just because I got pissed, I deleted my twig file, when I went to refresh the page - no errors (and of course no form, duh). So I made a new twig file (insert Bender reference), with only {{ form_start(form)}} and form_end(form), and for some reason everything is working now... I have no idea why, but I am happy.

Comment: Why were you rendering form twice (with `{{ form() }}` and `{{ form_start() }}`/`{{ form_end() }}`)?

Comment: I am new at this symfony and twig business... i saw it somewhere probably. after I removed it, all is well, but now I'm having trouble styling things, because symfony is  terrible for a beginner like me, why do they have to reinvent the wheel...